How to retrieve SMS pack details and total SMS sent using OVH SMS API?
I am working with the OVH SMS API (https://eu.api.ovh.com/console/?section=%2Fsms&branch=v1#get-/sms) and trying to retrieve specific details about my SMS service. However, I am struggling to find the right endpoints to get the following information:

Total number of SMS in the pack (the total quota for my service).
Total number of SMS consumed (for the entire service, not per user or sender).

I've reviewed the API documentation and explored endpoints like GET /sms/{serviceName} and GET /sms/{serviceName}/serviceInfos. While these provide useful details about the service itself (e.g., service information, renewal settings, etc.), I couldn't find any clear way to determine the total SMS quota or the total number of SMS sent.
Does anyone know the correct API endpoints or approach to retrieve these two pieces of information?
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
